# Could Mars be terraformed by redirecting an asteroid to hit it?

Tags: mars, terraforming

If so, what kind of asteroid would be best?

Comment: Recommend reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraforming_of_Mars and editing the question to clarify intent.

Comment: @GremlinWranger - in my previous journal submission, both peer-reviewers argued for rejection. And in both cases, the main argument was my references to Wikipedia. What do you think of Wikipedia as a source for scientific references? (I'll delete this comment when the conversation is over.)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142824/discussion-on-question-by-brettyeager-could-mars-be-terraformed-by-redirecting-a); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

That's a massively ambiguous question, sure any kind of asteroid impact is going to have some effect on mars but the extent and type of the change will differ massively depending on the composition and size of the asteroid.

It is also important to note that Mars's weak gravity means that lighter molecules are stripped from the atmosphere (the rate depends significantly on the molecule in question) but to terraform mars to have an oxygen/nitrogen atmosphere would require a continual supply as oxygen and nitrogen would burn off at a vastly greater rate than on earth.

Finally bar smashing something like a dwarf planet into mars you are not going to have a significant impact on the planet long term. The reason asteroids have major impacts on the earth is that the dust they create changes the climate for a few to tens of years. On a geological scale the impact is minor and the time period is short. However, the impact that those few years have on the ecosystem are very significant and the resulting extinctions and evolutions continue to have major impacts over long time periods. The ecosystem then in turn impacts the geology (e.g. by changing CO2 levels) meaning that an asteroid impact with (geologically) insignificant direct impacts can indirectly cause massive changes.

Comment: While it's true that mars is losing its atmosphere faster than earth, it's a process that takes hundreds of millions of year, and thus, not really relevant to terraforming capable civilisation. By the time it loses it's atmosphere,   you're probably be more worried about the sun EOL

Comment: It's not an issue with it's current atmosphere but that it because it's current atmosphere is mostly CO2 which has a high molecular mess and thus a low thermal velocity. Oxygen and nitrogen would burn off vastly faster (I would need to check but I think the figure is on the order of 10,000yrs which considering that terraforming takes at least a few hundred is short enough to matter)

Comment: I actually tried to find a definite answer on that but could not find any. It's worth pointing that terraforming is not necessarily adding nitrogen or oxygen tho.

Comment: Terraforming literally means making a planet like earth so yes it does mean adding nitrogen and oxygen. If you're a little less fussy it may be possible to use something else instead of nitrogen but you definitely need breathable amounts of oxygen.

Comment: I don't exactly agree, the goal is to make it closer to earth, not necessarily like earth. An atmosphere that would allow you to breathe with oxygen masks but no vacuum suit would still be considered terraforming for exemple

Comment: @Antzi, Ok I agree that is better than nothing but terraforming does literally mean "earth-shaping" and is almost always discussed in terms of making a planet liveable. It is also important to note that just because the pressure is sufficiently high doesn't mean that it's safe to walk around in an atmosphere. There will be a complex interplay between biology and chemistry that determines whether or not an atmosphere is safe. I don't know of any studies into that but I could easily believe that it could be a very wide or very narrow range.

Comment: I also dubious that there would be sufficient reasons to go to the enormous effort of adding enough gas to Mars's atmosphere to make the pressure survivable without fully terraforming it. On the kind of gargantuan scale we are discussing things like simply doming the entire planet become viable.

Comment: given that an ecosystem on that scale could become self-sufficient and the vegetation would both stabilise the Martian soil and regulate the atmosphere not to mention removing the requirement for every home, settlement, you name it to be made airtight and provided with air and air filtration I struggle to see why anyone would choose to go only half way.

Comment: We are well into the speculation domain here anyway. Terraforming a Mars is pure science fiction for now.